# Ubuntu Touch: no onscreen keyboard in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, ubuntu-touch, bq, onscreen-keyboard, m10

How can I open an on-screen keyboard in Firefox on Ubuntu Touch (bq M10, OTA10.1)? I've tried in both tablet and desktop mode, and no keyboard pops up. I tried some other things, such as dragging from the bottom, without any luck.

Firefox, despite being preinstalled, seems to be a pure desktop app. LibreOffice (also not adapted for Touch) appears to have the same problem.

Comment: This seems to be a known bug actually: https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-pocket-desktop/+bug/1543351

Comment: The next issue I would face if the keyboard was available, is the the URL bar is far too small and there does not seem any way to increase the size. I have raised this before, bit as yet there is no comments or fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searching some more I found that this seems to be a known bug actually: https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-pocket-desktop/+bug/1543351

This is the latest comment at this point:

> kevin gunn (kgunn72) wrote on 2016-04-15: #6
>
> just confirming, this is definitely on our todo list as a high priority.

UPDATE 2016-07-06: the fix is currently in testing, and has been available through the rc-proposed channel for the last week. It is expected to be available in the OTA-12 stable release (mid July).

UPDATE 2016-12-27: the fix is out in stable for some time now.

Comment: High priority, I would have it down as a blocker. Without the keyboard option it kind of makes the browser unusable until it is fixed. That is unless people want to copy and paste.

Comment: Seems like now Firefox is not in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is already fixed on rc-proposed channel.

> Launchpad Janitor (janitor) wrote on 2016-06-16:  #13
>
> This bug was fixed in the package libertine -
>   1.2+16.10.20160615.1-0ubuntu1

https://plus.google.com/u/0/+MichaelHall119/posts/ZhGsYNnRbnH

Comment: Great news. Lets hope that the size of the browser is fixed soon too and then we will have another browser we can use on our phones and tablets.