# I cant type on Firefox in my new m10 tablet

Tags: firefox

Why the typing on Firefox dosent work?is it working with keyboard, and not touch screen ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, if you're on OTA-10.1 then the onscreen keyboard isn't popping up for the 'legacy' apps like Firefox, LibreOffice etc.

This should be fixed in OTA-11 (the software update will be out in the next week or so) but for now an external keyboard if you have one (USB or Bluetooth) is the easiest way around this.

A similar question was asked here:

[Ubuntu Touch: no onscreen keyboard in Firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/759598/ubuntu-touch-no-onscreen-keyboard-in-firefox)

and in the answers it appears to be a bug that they are working on fixing.